# Run Mongodb Server as Service and mongod instance

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

I am using ubuntu and can run mongodb server by the following command

```
systemctl start mongodb
```

But, if i want to run Mongodb by `mongod`

```
mongod --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb
```

it gives me Permission Denied error. 
Adding `sudo` before the `mongod` command fix the error and the Server starts.
But now, earlier command

```
systemctl start mongodb
```

won't work and says `too many files open`

So, I change the owner of the folder `/var/log/mongodb` and `/var/lib/mongodb` by the following commands.

```
sudo chown -R  mongodb:mongodb /var/log/mongodb
sudo chown -R  mongodb:mongodb /var/lib/mongodb
```

Now, MongoDb server started by `systemctl` command but again `mongod` command gives me error.
So, Is there any way to run **Mongodb Server** by both ways i.e, by using `systemctl` and `mongod` command.

**Thanks**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following command has solved my problem

```
sudo -u mongodb mongod --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb
```

The `-u mongodb` after `sudo` runs the `mongod` with **mongodb** user. So,I don't have to change owner of folder `/var/lib/mongodb` to mongodb.

Now, I am able to start **Mongodb Server** as **Service** and also by **mongod**.

Comment: To avoid potential problems like permission issues it would be best to start and stop MongoDB consistently. I recommend always using the service definition. If you really need to start manually (for example, to temporarily add an extra parameter without editing the config) it would be better to use the same config file eg: `sudo -u mongodb mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf`.

Comment: Actually, I don't need so often to run it manually but sometimes i need to use bindip to let access database if i connected to network. But my problem is that there is an error cannot assign requested header, if i am not connected to network. then, I need that

Comment: I don't want to edit `/etc/mongod.conf` everytime.